# PagingAndSortingRepository - custom pageable response structure

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, controller, spring-data, response

Is there a way to simplify the structure returned from this controller:

```
@GetMapping
public Iterable<Task> getAll(@PathParam("page") int page) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 3);

    return taskRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

Right now the body of the response is as follows:

*localhost:8080/api/task?page=2*

```
{
    "content": [
        ...
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 6,
        "pageSize": 3,
        "pageNumber": 2,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalElements": 19,
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 7,
    "number": 2,
    "size": 3,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 3,
    "first": false,
    "empty": false
}
```

Is there any way to strip down on this data? What if I am not interested in sorting right now and only want to return something like this:

```
{
    "content": [
        ...
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "pageSize": 3,
        "pageNumber": 2,
        "totalElements": 19,
    },
}
```

So the current response just has too many properties I don't really need. What is a good way to achieve this? Should I be doing this completely differently if I want to customize it so much?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another way is to create a custom page class as you want and create from your data and return

```
@Data
public class CustomPage<T> {
  List<T> content;
  CustomPageable pageable;

  public CustomPage(Page<T> page) {
    this.content = page.getContent();
    this.pageable = new CustomPageable(page.getPageable().getPageNumber(),
        page.getPageable().getPageSize(), page.getTotalElements());
  }

  @Data
  class CustomPageable {
    int pageNumber;
    int pageSize;
    long totalElements;

    public CustomPageable(int pageNumber, int pageSize, long totalElements) {

      this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
      this.pageSize = pageSize;
      this.totalElements = totalElements;
    }
  }
}
```

And use like this

```
@GetMapping
public CustomPage<Task> getAll(@PathParam("page") int page) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 3);
    return new CustomPage<Task>(taskRepository.findAll(pageable));
}
```

*Note:* *Here @Data of Lombok used for setter getter etc.*

Comment: Good idea creating the CustomPage

Comment: I was kind of hoping that there was a way to configure the repository to not even spit out these extra values in the first place and maybe improve performance just a tiny bit as a result.

This normalization approach looks really clean and is easy to understand though. I like it.

Comment: @RaulŠpilev Jpa return data with pagination data using `Page` class object, or you can get List only but for total element you have to do count query separately then. If say about optimization it's not that much considerable optimization at all.

Answer (score 1):

- It looks like you have to create custom `JsonSerializer` with `@JsonComponent` annotation.
- I will copy the code for reference but you can see it here. [PageImpl JSON serialization](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2018/2018-06-10-pageimpl-json-serialization-with-spring-boot-2)

```
    @JsonComponent
    public class PageImplJacksonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PageImpl<?>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(PageImpl page, 
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, 
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) 
                          throws IOException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("content", page.getContent());
        jsonGenerator.writeBooleanField("first", page.isFirst());
        jsonGenerator.writeBooleanField("last", page.isLast());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("totalElements", page.getTotalElements());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("numberOfElements", 
                                       page.getNumberOfElements());

        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("size", page.getSize());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("number", page.getNumber());
        //sort omitted 

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
      }
    }
```