# How do I make a DTO for the Page<> interface?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dto, pageable

I am writing an online store using `Spring Boot` (MVC) and `Hiberbate`. The problem is that when I get a list of drinks, JSON gives me unnecessary information from the `Page` interface. I don't know how you can create an `DTO` for the `interfaces` to get rid of these fields. What should I do in this situation. Can someone have a ready-made solution?

[image]

```java
    public Page<DrinkDTO> getAllDrinks(int page, int pageSize) {

        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("id"));

        final Page<Drink> drinks = drinkRepository.findAll(pageRequest);

        return drinkMapper.drinksToDrinksDTO(drinks);
    }
```

Comment: A way is write a custom `Page` for this where you can remove them [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087937/4207306)

Comment: If you don't want the page info, don't return a page.  Get the page info:  `drinks.getContent()`.  Then you can add any information you do want in a wrapper class.

Comment: @User - Upvote don't say Thanks You are the best, Man!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomPage {

    Long totalElements;

    int totalPages;

    int number;

    int size;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class PageDTO<T> {

    List<T> content;

    CustomPage customPage;

    public PageDTO(Page<T> page) {
        this.content = page.getContent();
        this.customPage = new CustomPage(page.getTotalElements(),
                page.getTotalPages(), page.getNumber(), page.getSize());
    }
```

Service for example:

```java
public PageDTO<DrinkDTO> getAllDrinks(int page, int pageSize) {

        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("id"));

        final Page<Drink> drinks = drinkRepository.findAll(pageRequest);

        return new PageDTO<DrinkDTO>(drinkMapper.drinksToDrinksDTO(drinks));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I use native query and then I  i do dto projections most of the time.

Here is an example of DTO projection

```
public interface OvertimeRequestView {
public Long getId();

public String getEmployeeFirstName();

public String getEmployeeLastName();

public Long getOvertimeHours();

public Date getOvertimeDate();

public String getDescription();

public String getStatus();

public String getApproverName();

public default String getEmployeeFullName() {
    String lastName = this.getEmployeeLastName();
    String firstName = this.getEmployeeFirstName();
    if (null != firstName) {
        return firstName.concat(" ").concat(lastName);
    }
    return lastName;
}

}
```

and here is the repository with a native query. notice that since the query returns 'id' column I have a getId() method in the dto above,and since it has employeeFirstName i have getEmployeeFirstName() in the dto and so on. Notice also that I include a count query, without a count query, the queries sometime fail especially if the queries are complex and contain joins

```
@Query(value = "select ovr.id,\n" +
        "       u.first_name       as employeeFirstName,\n" +
        "       u.last_name        as employeeLastName,\n" +
        "       ovr.overtime_date  as overtimeDate,\n" +
        "       ovr.description  as description,\n" +
        "       ovr.overtime_hours as overtimeHours\n" +
        "from overtime_requests  ovr\n" +
        "         left join employees e on ovr.employee_id = e.id\n" +
        "         left join users u on e.user_id = u.id",
        nativeQuery = true,
        countQuery = "select count(ovr.id)\n" +
                "from overtime_requests  ovr\n" +
                "         left join employees e on ovr.employee_id = e.id\n" +
                "         left join users u on e.user_id = u.id")
public Page<OvertimeRequestView> getAllActive(Pageable pageable);
```

For more you can check from  [spring data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)