# How to extend CollectionModel/PagedModel in Spring Hateoas?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

A hypermedia response that needs to be consumed by one of my services looks like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "content": [
      {
        "createdBy": "...",
        "createdDate": "2020-03-07T14:21:27.507Z",
        "id": "...",
        "name": "item1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": ".."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "..."
    },
  },
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "totalItems": 20,
  "pageSize": 10
}
```

See how the paging related info is not what's expected by Spring Hateoas PagedModel which should have a single "page" property instead of individual ones for pageNumber, totalItems and pageSize:

```
  "page": {
    "size": 2,
    "totalElements": 1000,
    "totalPages": 500,
    "number": 5
  }
```

What I did in the end was to extend CollectionModel by adding those individual properties. This does work correctly deserialising a response shown above. But, all the CollectionModel constructors are now deprecated and the alternative is to use "CollectionModel.of", which however returns just CollectionModel.

What's the right way of customising paging information in using Spring Hateoas?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can write your own custom paging response class and pass the `PagedModel` in the constructor. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087937/4207306) is an example for `Page`, you can do same for PageModel