# Convert String to Sort with in Spring REST RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-rest

I want to do a custom Page and Pageable class because I am not really satisfied with the JSON got from these Spring classes. For that, I have two POJO with a converter function to Pageable to use PagingAndSortingRepository interface.
I want to reuse Spring Sort in my CustomPageable, but when I call my API, Spring fails to convert my String `sort=foo,asc` in a Sort object. I have checked the PageRequest class to do how it work and I don't understand why the conversion doesn't work in the case of my POJO.

Here is my endpoint:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/versions", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomPage<VersionDto>> getVersions(CustomPageable pageable) {
        final var page = repository.findAll(pageable.toSpringPageable()).map(version -> new VersionDto(version.getId()));
        final var customPage = CustomPage.from(page, VersionResource.class, ressource -> ressource.getVersions(null));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customPage);
    }
```

And here is my CustomPageable class:

```java
@Data
public class CustomPageable {

    private final int limit;
    private final int offset;
    private final Sort sort;

    public CustomPageable(Integer limit, Integer offset, Sort sort) {
        this.offset = offset == null ? 0 : offset;
        this.sort = sort;
        if(limit == null && offset == null)
            this.limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            this.limit = Objects.requireNonNullElse(limit, 20);
    }

    public Pageable toSpringPageable() {
        return PageRequest.of(offset, limit, sort);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "?limit=" + limit + "&offset=" + offset;
    }
}
```

The query I do:

```
localhost:8080/versions?sort=releaseTime,asc
```

The error:

```
Field error in object 'customPageable' on field 'sort': rejected value [releaseTime,asc]; codes [typeMismatch.customPageable.sort,typeMismatch.sort,typeMismatch.org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [customPageable.sort,sort]; arguments []; default message [sort]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.domain.Sort'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.domain.Sort': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: Please have a look of this thread,if it can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087074/pagingandsortingrepository-custom-pageable-response-structure

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems that the solution is close to what I already have except that his CustomPage takes a Page in parameter.

Comment: I had the same idea/problem. How did you resolve?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a better solution that this one.